# React-router universal. Why Root component does not re-render?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-router, universal, isomorphic-javascript

I have universal app (server rendering).
My routes.js looks like this

#### routes.js

```
<Route path="/" component={Root}>
  <Route path="sales/:id" component={View} />
  ...
</Route>
```

--

#### Root.js

```
class Root extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header {...someProps} />
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

--

#### server.js

```
app.use((req, res) => {
  match({ routes, location: req.url }, (error, redirectLocation, renderProps) => {
    if (error) {
      ...
    } else if (redirectLocation) {
      ...
    } else if (renderProps) {
      const initialState = {};
      const store = configureStore(initialState);

      fetchComponentData(store.dispatch, renderProps.components, renderProps.params).then(() => {
         const html = renderToString(
           <Provider store={store}>
             <RouterContext {...renderProps} />
           </Provider>
         );

        res.status(200).send(renderFullPage({ html, initialState: store.getState()}));
      });
    } else {
      ...
    }
  });
});
```

My Root and View components connected to store (redux). 
It works well without server rendering and initial rendering on server works good. Problem begins when I am trying to change the state and expect Root component get new props and re-render the tree, but in my case Root component is not re-renders and View component re-renders.

I can't understand how can it be? Why part of my tree is just static html?

UPDATE:
I have not found answer yet, but I assume that Root just not giving new state. If so why Root component is not connected to the store?

Comment: I'd like to know too!